# Excel 2016 - How to figure out what object isn't loading

Tags: excel

I have an add-in that is trying to load some sort of object and not finding it in Excel. I get 3 errors:

> Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine
>
> System Error &&H80010105 (-2147417851). The server threw an exception.
>
> Compile error in hidden module: GlobalMacros. This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application.  Click "Help" for information on how to correct this error.

I know in previous versions of Excel I could 'tick' an option called 'Break in Class Modules' and I would be able to figure out what the offending dll or ocx file is. But I can't seem to find it in Excel 2016!!

Comment: Is the add-in yours? I.e. are you able to see its code? If so, look in Tools, References and check if there are refs marked "MISSING: ". Alternatively, does the code use any API calls which haven't been updated to cater for 64 bit Office? Are you using any ActiveX controls? And finally, if this does not detect anything try repairing your Office installation as it can cause bogus compile errors.

Comment: No - the code isn't mine :(  It does use APIs, but those are installed with the add-in and have 64-bit installed as expected.  There are some controls, yes, all MS controls like mscomctl.ocx, mscomct2.ocx, and comct32.ocx.  I made sure they were registered and up to date.  I also tried repairing Office with no success.

Comment: If your Office version is 64 bit then the mscomctl controls won't work. Uninstall 64 bit Office and install 32 bit instead.

Comment: I have Office 2016, 32-bit

Comment: Best to contact the person that wrote the add-in.